# How to Key-Value-Observe the rotation of a CALayer?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I can access the value like this:

```
NSNumber* rotationZ = [myLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

But for some reason, if I try to KV-observe that key path, I get a compiler error. First, this is how I try to do it:

```
[myLayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z" options:0 context:nil];
```

The compiler tells me:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   addObserver: forKeyPath:@"rotation.z"
>   options:0x0 context:0x528890] was sent
>   to an object that is not KVC-compliant
>   for the "rotation" property.'

what I don't get is, why I can access that z value by KVC key path, but not add an observer to it. Does this make sense?

How else could I observe the z value of that matrix? I don't care about the other values of the matrix. Only the z rotation. Any other way to access and observe it?

Answer (score 1):

The `transform` property for the `CALayer` is a struct, not an object, so it isn't KVC compliant.

What you should be able to do is, instead of binding to the Z rotation, bind to the transform property and pull the Z value out whenever you get the KVO notification.

I think the confusion here is that when you use dot notation on an NSObject, you're really using that object's `- (id)property` and `- (void)setProperty` methods, which are KVC compliant. When you use dot notation on a struct, you're accessing a member of that struct, not calling a method.

Comment: It seems to be impossible to observe it at all. I can observe the backgroundColor. But when I try it on the layer.transform, nothing happens on rotation. When I set the layer as observer object and just set "transform" for keyPath, same problem. Seems like there is no way to observe changes in the transform matrix.

Comment: Same here. It looks like you simply can't observe it. To bad. It's probably a performance issue Apple wants to stay away from during an animation.