# IOS - Detect changes to CALayer transform

Tags: ios, calayer

As seen in [How to Key-Value-Observe the rotation of a CALayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1260704/608157), you can't observe the `transform` using KVO.

Is there some other way to detect changes to the CALayer transform?

I would like to know when the scale changes when sitting in a UIScrollView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260704/how-to-key-value-observe-the-rotation-of-a-calayer - Are you suggesting that I add KVO on the (UIView*)self.delegate?

Comment: That would have been good information to add to the original question. (added link to question)

Comment: How is the transform being changed? User interaction? Is there some other mechanism that can inform you of the change?

Comment: The short of it is I'm looking to replace CATiledLayer for better performance and control. CATiledLayer calls the UIView's drawRect when the next set of tiles is needed (zoom in this case). I'd like to have a drop-in replacement for CATiledLayer as a starting point. Thanks  [/action gets a coffee]

Comment: You should be able to get really good performance using CATiledLayer. Focus on that instead.

Comment: I took the stock PhotoScroller demo, modified it to run on an iPad in the project settings, and profiled the time spent outside vs inside drawRect. The time spent outside of drawRect is much greater than time spent inside. I can watch the tiles load. I grant the tile sizes are smaller for this quick setup, but the effect is the same if corrected. I welcome your recommendations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35855/discussion-between-david-ronnqvist-and-nous)

Comment: Update for onlookers: Using very low resolution images behind the tiled layer can hide the loading effect very well.  This approach was used in the short term, but a new tiled layer was built that allows me to preload content for regions outside the viewport.